# GLSL how to tell the vertex shader to ignore the geometry shader

Tags: glsl

I want to run the geometry shader only if a certain uniform has some value, otherwise go directly to the fragment shader. I know I can duplicate the shader, but I wanted a more elegant solution. Any ideas?

Comment: The geometry shader can't be skipped or "ignored". But the vertices and its attributes can be "passed through" the geometry shader without manipulation. How would you write a vertex and a fragment shader that can be linked with and without a geometry shader?

Comment: Use a geometry shader and [Transform Feedback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback) to generate a "transformed" mesh. Possibly this can be done once at the begin of the application. Then you can draw all the geometry with a single shader program.

Comment: An other possible solution would be use [Program pipeline objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLSL_Object#Program_pipeline_objects), see also [Example/GLSL Separate Program Multi Stage](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Example/GLSL_Separate_Program_Multi_Stage)